# Fmdb Loop only fetch first entry in database IOS

Tags: ios, fmdb

i have two entries in my database

```
sqlite> select *from courses;
1|ME|273|Statics|MWF|02:20 pm-03:20 pm|James M. Pitarresi|LH 002
2|CS|328|Internet|TR|02:20 pm-03:20 pm|Steflik|eb 23
```

and i have following code but it does only show first entry in my database

```
   -(NSMutableArray *) getCourses
    {
         courses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
        [db open];  
        FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM courses"];

        if ([db hadError]) {
            NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
        }

        while([results next]) 
        {
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Subject"]];
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Course_Number"]];                
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Course_Title"]];                
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Days"]];               
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Time"]];            
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Instructor"]];                
            [courses addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"Location"]];  

        }

        NSLog(@"loop %@ ",courses);

        [results close];
        [db close];

        return courses; 

    }
```

my output is, it doesnt show second entry

> ```
> loop (
>     ME,
>     273,
>     Statics,
>     MWF,
>     "02:20 pm-03:20 pm",
>     "James M. Pitarresi",
>     "LH 002"
> )
> ```

any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know why but when i change the database name or create a new database problem solved